# Is there a container and method to add list B to list A so that B is a subset of A

Tags: rust, containers

is there a container and/or a method in Rust to add a list of elements (B) to another list of elements (A) so that B is a subset of A? Furthermore A and B can both contain duplicates.

Example:

```
A = {1, 2, 3}
B = {2, 2, 3}
```

I'd like to get:

```
A = {1, 2, 2, 3}
```

Update:

I want to solve project euler's 5th problem (https://projecteuler.net/problem=5). My current solution is the following:

```rust
fn prime_factors(mut n: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut factors = Vec::new();

    let mut p = 2;
    while n >= p * p {
        if n % p == 0 {
            factors.push(p);
            n /= p;
        } else {
            p += 1;
        }
    }
    factors.push(n);
    factors
}

pub fn smallest_multiple(n: i64) -> i64 {
    let mut factors: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();

    for p in 1..n + 1 {
        let pfs = prime_factors(p as i64);

        for ele in &pfs {
            let a = pfs.iter().filter(|n| *n == ele).count();
            let b = factors.iter().filter(|n| *n == ele).count();

            let diff = if a > b {
                a - b
            } else {
                continue;
            };

            for _ in 0..diff {
                factors.push(*ele);
            }
        }
    }
    factors.iter().product()
}
```

Is there any collection type or something in Rust to solve smallest_multiple()?

I know that this problem can be solved using gcd and lcm, like:

```rust
pub fn smallest_multiple2(n: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut res: u64 = 1;
    let gcd = |mut a: u64, mut b: u64| -> u64 {
        while a != 0 {
            let c = a;
            a = b % a;
            b = c;
        }
        b
    };

    let lcm = |a: u64, b: u64| -> u64 { a * (b / gcd(a, b)) };
    for i in 2..n + 1 {
        res = lcm(res, i);
    }
    res
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context why you need this?

Comment: Assume that B contains all prime factors of an natural number x_i and A contains all prime factors to represent all the sets of prime factors of the numbers x_1...x_n.

Comment: The confusing part is that a mathematical set does **not** contain duplicates. This is why I hoped that additional context would elucidate the underlying logic.

Comment: Yes, that's why I can't use `std::collections::HashSet`...

Comment: I want to solve project euler's 5th problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=5

Comment: This is probably not applicable in project euler, but in general you can use the multiset crate https://docs.rs/multiset/0.0.5/multiset/

Answer (score 0):

If your sequences are sorted, you can use function like this:

```
fn combine(first: &[u32], second:&[u32])->Vec<u32>{
    if first.is_empty(){
        return second.to_vec();
    }
    if second.is_empty(){
        return first.to_vec();
    }
    // I will assume that both sorted
    let mut first_counted: Vec<(u32, usize)> = Vec::with_capacity(first.len());
    for &item in first.iter(){
        match first_counted.last_mut(){
            Some(last) if last.0 == item =>{
                last.1 += 1;
            },
            _ => first_counted.push((item, 1)),
        };
    }

    let mut second_counted: Vec<(u32, usize)> = Vec::with_capacity(second.len());
    for &item in second.iter(){
        match second_counted.last_mut(){
            Some(last) if last.0 == item => {
                last.1 += 1;
            },
            _ => second_counted.push((item, 1)),
        };
    }
    let mut res = Vec::with_capacity(std::cmp::max(first.len(),second.len()));
    let mut fidx = 0;
    let mut sidx = 0;
    while fidx < first_counted.len() && sidx < second_counted.len(){
        let f = &first_counted[fidx];
        let s = &second_counted[sidx];
        match f.0.cmp(&s.0){
            std::cmp::Ordering::Less=>{
                res.resize(res.len()+f.1, f.0);
                fidx+=1;
            },
            std::cmp::Ordering::Equal=>{
                res.resize(res.len()+std::cmp::max(f.1, s.1), f.0);
                fidx+=1;
                sidx+=1;
            },
            std::cmp::Ordering::Greater=>{
                res.resize(res.len()+s.1, s.0);
                sidx+=1;
            },
        }
    }
    res
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(combine(&[1, 2, 3], &[2, 2, 3]), vec![1,2,2,3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap` or `BTreeMap` to keep track of each number (as the key) and how many times it repeats (as the value). Then you can update one of those maps based on the items in the other. If you want to keep the numbers in order then `BTreeMap` will do this automatically:

```
use itertools::repeat_n;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn count_repeats(inputs: &[u32]) -> BTreeMap<u32, usize> {
    inputs.iter().fold(BTreeMap::new(), |mut map, &n| {
        let count = map.entry(n).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
        map
    })
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = count_repeats(&[1, 2, 3]);
    let b = count_repeats(&[2, 2, 3]);

    for (n, count_b) in b {
        a.entry(n)
            .and_modify(|count_a| *count_a = count_b.max(*count_a))
            .or_insert(count_b);
    }

    let result: Vec<u32> = a
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|(&n, &count)| repeat_n(n, count))
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", result); // [1, 2, 2, 3]
}
```